# Add two variables to make a path of directory

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, constants

I want to concatenate the path of a directory which is `"/sdcard/hello.txt"`, but my problem is the first half(`/sdcard`) is defined in `#define format` and 2nd is `const char *file_path("/hello.txt")` which I am taking from the user.

So to make a full path I have to concatenate these two halfs to make a full path of a directory.

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MOUNT_POINT "/sd_card"
using namespace std;

class SD_Card {
 public:
  void sd_card_init(void);
  void create_and_writeFile(const char* file_path);
};


void SD_Card::create_and_writeFile(const char* file_path) {

  // First create a file.
  //const char *file_hello = MOUNT_POINT"/hello.txt";

  const char* file_hello = strcat(MOUNT_POINT, file_path);

  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Opening file %s", file_hello);
  FILE* f = fopen(file_hello, "w");
  if (f == NULL) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }

  fprintf(f, "Hello %s!\n", card->cid.name);
  fclose(f);
  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "File written");
}

void app_main() {
  SD_Card cObj;
  cObj.create_and_writeFile("/hello.txt");
}
```

I am getting this error:

```sh
/main/SD_Card.cpp: In member function 'void SD_Card::create_and_writeFile(const char*)':
  ../main/SD_Card.cpp:144:63: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' 
  [-Wwrite-strings]
      const char *file_hello = strcat(MOUNT_POINT,file_path);
```

I am new in CPP, please help me with how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a C++ Compiler, then use the C++ STL `fstream` and `string`.

Comment: `strcat` will modify the first argument and put the content of second argument in the memory of first argument. But you are passing non-modifiable string literal as the first argument, so compiler (rightfully) complains. Using `std::string` instead of C function will indeed be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Could you please share some example code for this, I have tried but not working.

Comment: Since several years we have a ````filesystem```` library in C++. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem Everything that you need is already existing. And if you read the cppreference, you will find many examples.

Answer (score 1):

[`strcat`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) will use the first parameter as the destination. What you are doing is wrong since you are specifying as destination a string literal (`"/sdcard"`).

Since you're using the ESP API I'm assuming you want to remain in C'ish programming and avoid STL and friends so the least amount of code that could fix the problem involves [printing into a buffer](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

```cpp
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

{
  // Remove this line:
  // const char *file_hello = strcat(MOUNT_POINT,file_path);

  char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  snprintf(buf, BUFFER_SIZE, "%s%s", MOUNT_POINT, file_path);
  // buf now holds the concatenated strings :) 

  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Opening file %s", buf);
  FILE* f = fopen(buf, "w");
}
```

Of course if you can use the Standard library, the question is tagged as C++ after all, you can simply do:

```cpp
#include <string>

const string MOUNT_POINT{"/sdcard"};

{
  auto file_hello = MOUNT_POINT + file_path;

  // The rest is similar, use `.c_str()` to pass a C string e.g.
  FILE *f = fopen(file_hello.c_str(), "w");
}
```